# Draw 3 textures and view the first through the two others

Tags: android, libgdx

I use LibGDX and I have 3 images.
The first is the background, the second is a wall and the third is a window.

I need to place the 3 textures on top of the other in this order:
first is the background then wall then window.

I want to be able to see the background through the window so the wall that is in the place where the window will be transparent.

I can't use a fixed image of wall with a window because I adjust the window's size according to the resolution and the window is not a quadrilateral so I cant use a small image of wall and then draw it multiple times except where is the window.

Here is an image 
http://s27.postimg.org/dmz3ion8j/Untitled.png

Answer (score 0):

I think thats a game design related issue. I can give a try on that!

I would create a tileable wall, i.e, create a texture that could be "looped" without compromising the UI.

Than would simply calculate where to place the window and where not to, and fill the rest with that tileable texture!

I assume that the user can make different configurations of that window, am I right? Otherwise, I really don't get why you don't simply create the window+wall texture together.

Hope that helps!